# How to programmatically add active style to header control links using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an unordered list for my navigation in my header control. The header control is called on each of my other pages.

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Store</li>
</ul>
```

What is the best way to programmatically change the active class to the About page when I load it?

I'm using C# for this project.

Comment: Is the header control a user control, or is it just HTML?

Comment: What type of project it is - WebForms, MVC, WebBrowser, some command line tool that greps HTML...?

Comment: @neoistheone Yes it is a user control.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov WebForms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a public property to the user control.

I assume this data is in a data structure when your page is initialized. The property type should be of the appropriate type to identify that data. Then when the page is rendered, the control should take the value of the property into consideration for how the data is rendered.

This might involved setting `runat=server` for each list item and then setting the `CssClass` property for the appropriate one. I personally took a different approach, writing the raw code to generate the HTML. I can think of other options as well.

An example of the first approach might look something like this (untested):

**ascx**

```
<ul>
    <li id="HomeList" runat="server">Home</li>
    <li id="AboutList" runat="server">About</li>
    <li id="StoreList" runat="server">Store</li>
</ul>
```

**User Control cs**

```
public string ActiveItem { get; set; }

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ActiveItem != null)
    {
        if (ActiveItem == "Home")
            HomeList.CssClass = "active";
        if (ActiveItem == "About")
            HomeAbout.CssClass = "active";
        if (ActiveItem == "Store")
            HomeStore.CssClass = "active";
    }
}
```

**Page cs**

```
UserControl1.ActiveItem = "Home";
```

Getting much more specific would probably require more information about those data structures and the inner working of your user control.

Comment: Jonathan, can you please provide an example?

Comment: I've updated my answer but don't understand why you are being so tight lipped about the details of your data and control.

Comment: Jonathan, what if the header control is included on the Default.aspx? I can't access HomeList from Default.cs.

Comment: No, you would only access it from your user control. As I explained in my original answer, you need to add a public property to your user control, which should handle so it sets the CssClass of the appropriate item. Default.aspx will just access that public property.